# Repeatable animation in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I need to make a **repeatable animation** when hover a link.

I've made a route link component which contains that animation:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'routelink',
  template: `<a [@hoverState]="isHover" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter()"  (mouseleave)="mouseLeave()" routerLink="{{routerLink}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{title}}</a>`,
  styleUrls: [ 'routelink.component.css' ],
  animations : [
    trigger('hoverState', [
      state('false', style({
        transform: 'scale(1)'
      })),
      state('true',   style({
        transform: 'scale(1.5)'
      })),
      transition('false <=> true', animate('1000ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
})

export class RouteLinkComponent { 
  @Input()
  title : String;

  @Input()
  routerLink : String;

  isHover : String;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isHover = "false";
  }

  mouseEnter() {
      this.isHover = "true"; 
  }

  mouseLeave() {
      this.isHover = "false"; 
  }
}
```

After hovering the link - it scales as expected but stops when it reaches maximum size. As you can see I used `ease-in-out` in that animation.
What am I missing here ?

**UPDATE:**

I've created a plunker for this question:
**https://plnkr.co/edit/e7sN2Aoz2sr68CrWxtgo?p=preview**

Comment: Please provide plunker :)

Comment: make isHover as boolean value

Comment: Also ease-in and ease-out separate not togather

Comment: when I make isHover as boolean --> state doesn't work propely

Comment: @Kinduser I've created a plunker and updated my question

Comment: You want it to animate the size up and down while user is hovering this element?

Comment: @Kinduser exactly ! Scale in and out repeatedly while user is hovering the element

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/F1DH78GGsI6gdSwpwOZH?p=preview Check it. It can be done easier than using complicated angular animations.

Comment: @Kinduser nice! thanks!

Comment: @ohadinho I've made full answer, you can upvote if you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `css` animation is enough.

**[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/F1DH78GGsI6gdSwpwOZH?p=preview)**.